# How to display a Foreign key serializer as a dropdown?

Tags: python, django

I have three different models:

```
class Province(Model):
    province = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class BaseCase(ModelWithStamps):
    ...
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Event(BaseEvent):
   ....
    @property
    def province(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'case'):
            return self.case.province
        return None

    @property
    def province_id(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'case'):
            return self.case.province.id
        return None
```

And I have a serializer:

```
class BaseEditCaseSerializer(...):
    ....
    province = serializers.ModelField(model_field=Case()._meta.get_field('province'),
                                      required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ManualEvent
        fields = (..., 'province')
```

Even, the province is a foreign key, the province field is displayed as a "text field" in front end and I cannot change it from there.

I want to display it as a dropdown (`Province.objects.all()`).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved:

```
province = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Province.objects.values_list('id', 'province'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'ModelChoiceField':

```
from django.db.models import Model
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Province, BaseCase, Event

class BaseEditCaseSerializer(...):
  province = serializers.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Province.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)

  class Meta:
      model = ManualEvent
      fields = (..., 'province')
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the province field as a dropdown in the serializer, you can use the ChoiceField with the choices populated from the Province model.

---

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Province, BaseCase, Event

class BaseEditCaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
province = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Province.objects.all().values_list('id', 'province'),
                                   required=False, allow_null=True)

class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('province', ...)
```

In the province field, we use ChoiceField and provide the choices as a list of tuples (id, province) obtained from the Province model using the values_list() method.

Make sure you import the necessary classes and update the model import as per your codebase.

With this modification, the province field should be displayed as a dropdown in the front-end, populated with the options from the Province model.

1. DRF Serializers:
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
2. Serializer Fields:
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/
3. ChoiceField:
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield
4. ModelField:
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#modelfield